# insert shortcode after second paragraph by post id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

let's say I have **2 shortcodes**

> [digi id="1"] & [digi id="2"]

I want to add these shortcodes after the second paragraph in content but not in all posts, in specific posts by post id.
for example shortcode1 in **post IDs:**

> 1,2,3

and shortcode2 in **post IDs:**

> 4,5,6

I know how to add codes in all posts but the problem is I need to do this for specific post ids.

Comment: Kindly add some working code example to understand your question better!

Comment: that depends on how you are looping through the posts.
Include some working code please.